# Rails Checkout Form/View: User Input > Review Input > Checkout

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, view, controller, stripe-payments

I'm in the process of making a job board. I was wondering if anyone has experience making a 1-2-3 process form, where a record isn't saved until after a stripe payment is made, and after 2 other views have been rendered. Example [link](https://ads.simplyhired.com/simplypost/post-job/). In the first view, the user inputs the job position, the next view will be an overview of their posting (even though it hasn't been saved?), and the final view would be a stripe checkout. A point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to save the record between steps, but not move it into it's "final state" until the end. A state machine is perfect to solve this for you.

In state "a", you render the first form. Then, when it's requirements are met, you transition to state "b" and render the next form. You can even have your validations dependent on the state, so requirements for states "b" and "c" aren't holding up state "a" until it's valid and you move to "b".

Saving it between steps also lets you collect analytics on where the process is abandoned by users so you can improve it later.

You can present the payment screen as one of your states and once the payment is accepted you can mark the posting as finalized and start displaying it to visitors.

Bonus link: [state machines](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/state_machines.html)